# AppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders() doesn't return all installed widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

I use the following code to return all available (installed) widgets. But it doesn't return all of them. In my case, it returns 47 widgets, while the stock launcher has 73 widgets.

```
AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> infoList = mAppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders();

for (AppWidgetProviderInfo info : infoList) {

}
```

Comment: What the stock launcher depicts as "widgets" do not have to be app widgets available to other apps. They could be built-in features of the launcher that show up as "widgets" that the user can optionally add. I recommend comparing your results with those of other third-party launchers, not a pre-installed launcher.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just checked Microsoft and Nova Launchers and it's the same result (I have multiple launchers installed). I noticed they show other launchers widgets and system widgets that aren't retrieved by my code. But I noticed something in Nova launcher, the widgets that are not retrieved by my code (As Dropbox folder, Gmail label, Direct message, Direct dial, Contact, Adapt sound, Drive scan, etc) are marked as "Shortcut".

Comment: That is probably referring to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts. I think a launcher like yours would [use `LauncherApps`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps.html) as the starting point for finding available shortcuts, but I do not know the details.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare Indeed it turned out there are a shortcuts for activities not widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare's assistance, these extras are not widgets, they are shortcuts to activities that are fetched using the following code.

```
Intent shortcutsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT);
List<ResolveInfo> shortcuts = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shortcutsIntent, 0);
```